# How to connect Jquery draggable UI with mysql via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

I would like to drag elements in my horizontal list and than save the position in mysql.
[image]

The text sort=1&sort=2.... ist just for testing purpose.

this is my code in jquery

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
                stop: function(event, ui) {
                    var data = $(this).sortable('serialize', {key:"sort"});
                    $('#tags').text(data);
                    $.ajax({
                        data: data,
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'listpriority.php'
                    });
                }
            });
```

The sortable function is working. It serializes me the list.
Now on the server side i would like to recive the serialized data.

my php code:

```
<?php 
    print_r($_POST['sort']);
?>
```

But the print_r function show me only the length of the list.
the full php code should be:

```
<?php 
    include = ""; // the connection to sql

    if(isset($_POST['sort'])) {
        $sort = $_POST['sort'];
        $sql = "UPDATE tags SET position='".$sort."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
?>
```

Comment: try `var_dump($_POST);` to see if the contents of your data are in another key within the `$_POST` array

Comment: even though this is not part of the question, I highly advice you not to concat the posted value into a sql query without any validation of the given value due to the risk of sql injections. If you're not already aware of this security issue I suggest you take a look a this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: `array(1) { ["sort"]=> string(1) "5" }` this is what i get when i use the var_dump function

Comment: I think you'll need to get the needed values out of the `ui` object in js and add them to post-data manually. [Have a look here](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop)

Answer (score 1):

My solution for the problem:

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
                update: function(event, ui) {
                    var data = $(this).sortable('serialize', { key: "sort" });
                    $('#tags').text(data);
                    $.post("listpriority.php", {data});
                }
            });
```

i changed the `$.ajax` to `$.post` and than i echo out the data in php `echo($_POST['data']);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to get and set data from hidden field

```
<div class="main_div">
    <div class="inner">
        <span>1</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="original[]" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="new[]" class="new_ord" value="1">
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        <span>2</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="original[]" value="2">
        <input type="hidden" name="new[]" class="new_ord" value="2">
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        <span>3</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="original[]" value="3">
        <input type="hidden" name="new[]" class="new_ord" value="3">
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        <span>4</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="original[]" value="4">
        <input type="hidden" name="new[]" class="new_ord" value="4">
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        <span>5</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="original[]" value="5">
        <input type="hidden" name="new[]" class="new_ord" value="5">
    </div>
</div>
```

**And php script is**

```
if(isset($_POST['post']) == 1) {
        $original = $_POST['original'];
        $new_val = $_POST['new_val'];
        for ($i=0; $i < count($original); $i++) {
            $sql = 'UPDATE TABLE Table_name SET order="'.$new_val[$i].'" WHERE id="'.$original[$i].'"';
            echo $sql."\n\r";
        }
    }
```

See jquery code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nidhi_akbari_1994/p5uht7z0/) and uncomment ajax call portion

Maybe it helps you